# Storing MongoDB/ExpressJS query into an array and displaying into HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to learn how to get data that is already stored in MongoDB and display it as a table in HTML. I've never worked with HTML or JavaScript much so I decided to start by creating a script within my HTML code and display a simple table using a loop:

```
<div>
  <script>
    var words = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven"];
    var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    document.write('<table>');
      for (var i =0; i < words.length; i++){
         document.write('<tbody><tr><td>' + words[i] + '</td>' + '<td>' + numbers[i] + '</td></tr></tbody>' );
      }
    document.write('</table>');

  </script>
</div>
```

The output I got was:

```
One    1
Two    2
Three  3
Four   4
Five   5
Six    6
Seven  7
```

Now that I figured out how the syntax works, I would like to use something like NodeJS/ExpressJS/Mongoose to get documents from MongoDB and store them into an array and display them as a table.

My MongoDB Schema that already exists inside db `test` and collection `test1` is:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("fffffffffffffff"),
    "Words": "One",
    "Numbers": 1
}
{
    "_id": ObjectId("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
    "Words": "Two",
    "Numbers": 2
}
...
```

I would like to query and store the values of "Words" and "Numbers" from the documents into arrays `wordArray` and `numArray` and display them as a table.

I found these related questions:

[Displaying MongoDB Documents with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856809/displaying-mongodb-documents-with-html)

[Display MongoDB values in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653438/display-mongodb-values-in-html?rq=1)

[How to use HTML in Express framework with nunjucks- no jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912389/how-to-use-html-in-express-framework-with-nunjucks-no-jade/19913691#19913691)

How would I go about doing what I want? Which one of those links should I look at? Because I'm very lost and don't know where to start. Is there an easy way to do this? I tried doing the following:

```
<script>
//import express package
var express = require("express");

//import mongodb package
var mongodb = require("mongodb");

//MongoDB connection URL - mongodb://host:port/dbName
var dbHost = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";

//DB Object
var dbObject;

//get instance of MongoClient to establish connection
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

//Connecting to the Mongodb instance.
//Make sure your mongodb daemon mongod is running on port 27017 on localhost
MongoClient.connect(dbHost, function(err, db){
  if ( err ) throw err;
  dbObject = db;
});
//use the find() API and pass an empty query object to retrieve all records
dbObject.collection("test1").find({}).toArray(function(err, docs){
    if ( err ) throw err;
    var wordArray = [];
    var numArray = [];

    for ( index in docs){
      var doc = docs[index];

      var words = doc['Words'];

      var numbers = doc['Numbers'];

      wordArray.push({"value": words});
      numArray.push({"value" : numbers});
    }
}
</script>
```

Can I do something simple like this and then just access wordArray and numArray?

Comment: have you tried pulling data using mongoose yet?

Comment: Not yet, I couldn't find any good tutorials on how to use Mongoose

Comment: well i know the answer but you need knowledge of mongoose or mongodb

Comment: I know MongoDB but haven't worked with mongoose yet. Can you point me towards the answer? I'm just trying to learn how to build a website for personal use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright this example is based on the MongoDB driver, wether you use a wrapper such as mongoose or monk is desirable. First thing pull data from your db and store in in a array. eg after storage `arr = ['dta','nio']` to point this data into your view or web page you require a template binding engine , i normally use EJS due it's simplicity and natural feel.EJS combines data and a template to produce HTML. you thus bind JavaScript variables to html files. Here is a link to ejs.http://www.embeddedjs.com/

To get stated with mongoose here is a great link.https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications

Here is a link to EJS with node https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. That tutorial looks great! Thank you.